# How do I create a custom widget in angular2-json-schema-form

Tags: angular, angular-schema-form

Has anyone managed to create custom widgets and layouts for form controls using [angular2-json-schema-form](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form)? I cannot find links to any documentation or examples.

Comment: Did you by any chance figure this out? I'm in desperate need of this actually working.

Comment: @sjjk001 you can check out my sandbox here https://github.com/neil-coutinho/json-form-ajsf 

custom widgets are just like any other components. You can override existing layout controls with your widgets

Comment: This has been very helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. Note I have used https://github.com/hamzahamidi/ajsf's updated version. angular2-json-schema-form has not been maintained in a while.

Comment: I have this particular problem, I'm trying to create a widget for a property type object on the schema, but when I do it like in our example the 'this.jsf.initializrControl(this)' throws the following error 'core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function', do you have any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a repo or an example where I can take a look?

Comment: I have figured it out yesterday, what worked for me was making a widget for the object but not initializing the control from that widget component but making another widget for the object properties, binding layoutNode.items['property'], layoutIndex and dataIndex to the other widget component and initializing the control from the object widget, works like a charm. Thank you anyway though @Neil :)

Answer (score 1):

In their documentation it indicates that [you can create your own json-schema-form components/widgets](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form#changing-or-adding-widgets) and pass a mapping of them to the json-schema-form directive, thereby either creating your own form controls or overriding the defaults.

Here is the [source for the TEXTAREA component/widget](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form/blob/master/src/lib/src/widget-library/textarea.component.ts) as a reference for how to create your own form control.

Comment: Yes, Thank you.  I did check it out. Unfortunately they do not have a working example.